# unable to set gwt-button's covers in rounded form

Tags: java, html, css, gwt, stylesheet

Hi I have a button in my GUI which I have developed using GWT. Now I am unable to set button's corners as rounded. I tried using border-radius but its not effecting my button's look and feel at all.[image]

I am using "com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean" style sheet and MSThemeCompatible in .html file. I also referred http://css3please.com/ sit but still unable to get desired result.

```
.gwt-Button {
width:5em;
font-size: small;
font-family: Tahoma;
color: blue;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
```

}

Above is the my class for this button.

Can anybody suggest me anything regarding this and what am I doing wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: With what browser do you test?

Comment: I tried this on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I just used `button.setStylename("Mystyle")`; and it worked. Below see the screen shot.
If you have made any changes in standard.css or clean.css or any theme.css gwt overrides if it is not handled properly. So try giving a different style name and try it out
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean` style, which has the following CSS for the GWT-Button (located at `<PROJECT>\war\<MODULE>\gwt\clean\clean.css`):

```
.gwt-Button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  font-size:small;
  background: url("images/hborder.png") repeat-x 0px -2077px;
  border:1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
  border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Your `border-radius` is being overridden by the `gwt-Button` default style.

**Use a different class name.**

And use `button.setStyleName("yourClassName");` instead of `button.addStyleName("yourClassName");` so the default `gwt-Button` class doesn't affect your style.